Import Pillow on Python 3.12.4 virtual environment on Ubuntu 24.04
I am running Python 3.12.4 in a virtual environment under Ubuntu 24.04. Pillow 10.4.0 installed without warnings using the command: python -m pip install pillow.
However a script:
from PIL import Image
fails in the following way:
>>> from PIL import Image
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/mnt/SystemData/venvs/PRD/lib/python3.12/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 100, in <module>
    from . import _imaging as core
ImportError: cannot import name '_imaging' from 'PIL' (/mnt/SystemData/venvs/PRD/lib/python3.12/site-packages/PIL/__init__.py)

After Googling it appears that my problem may be that the C language module _image.so is not installed. What is the best way to correct this problem?

what is the version of your CPython, I had the same issue before I had to downgrade the version? check for conflicting packages python -c "from PIL import Image"

I was running under Python 3.12.4 in a virtual environment. Downgrading Python will not work in this case. Too much of my environment depends on Python 3.12.4.

No I mean CPYTHON ? not python check for conflicts packages using this python -c "from PIL import Image" try installing these libraries  sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y build-essential libjpeg-dev libz-dev libtiff-dev libfreetype6-dev liblcms2-dev libwebp-dev tcl-dev tk-dev python3-tk

I have no idea. Whatever comes with Ubuntu 24.04 which uses Python 3.12.3. I have never had to concern my self with CPYTHON so do not even know how to determine the version.

try doing this let see what happens sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y build-essential libjpeg-dev libz-dev libtiff-dev libfreetype6-dev liblcms2-dev libwebp-dev tcl-dev tk-dev python3-tk

I tried that import but it did not help, i think because I am using a virtual environment.

You didn't say how you ran the script. If you really installed with python -m pip install pillow you should be able to run python -m site to tell you where you Python looks for packages and pip show pillow to see where you installed it. The two should match.

As expected, both components are installed in the site_packages directory for the virtual environment. I ran the script by starting a Python REPL and manually entering the problematic text.

I replicated your entire environment with docker and the problem is not reproducible on my machine.
Maybe your /mnt is a "funny" filesystem - e.g. Samba/CIFS or something that doesn't properly preserve some attributes?
Anyway, here is what I did:
docker run -it ubuntu:24.04

Inside docker container:
apt update
apt install python3
apt install pip3
apt install python3.12-venv
python3 -m venv myenv
. myenv/bin/activate
pip install pillow

Then start Python REPL and run:
from PIL import Image

and everything works ok. I also tried under the vastly superior IPython REPL and that works fine too.

I was running in a vanilla Ubuntu 24.04 environment. If you do a find, does the C language model show up. It does not on my machine.
